# Can XPath do a foreign key lookup across two subtrees of an XML?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, subtree, xslkey

Say I have the following XML...

```
<root>
  <base>
    <tent key="1" color="red"/>
    <tent key="2" color="yellow"/>
    <tent key="3" color="blue"/>
  </base>
  <bucket>
    <tent key="1"/>
    <tent key="3"/>
  </bucket>
</root>
```

...what would the XPath be that returns that the "bucket" contains "red" and "blue"?

Comment: The XPath expression in the currently accepted answer doesn't select any "bucket" nodes at all. It selects "color" attributes. So this answer is wrong. dacracot, please, accept Jeni's answer, which is a good one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using XSLT, I'd recommend setting up a key:

```
<xsl:key name="tents" match="base/tent" use="@key" />
```

You can then get the `<tent>` within `<base>` with a particular `key` using

```
key('tents', $id)
```

Then you can do

```
key('tents', /root/bucket/tent/@key)/@color
```

or, if `$bucket` is a particular `<bucket>` element,

```
key('tents', $bucket/tent/@key)/@color
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work:

```
/root/base/tent[/root/bucket/tent/@key = @key ]/@color
```

Comment: The xpath works for the given XML but is not a generic solution. If the XML is:

<root>
... snip ...
  <bucket>
    <tent key="1" />
    <tent key="3" />
  </bucket>
  <bucket>
    <tent key="2" />
  </bucket>
</root>

then it will return all three colors.

Comment: This XPath expression doesn't select any "bucket" nodes at all. It selects "color" attributes. So this answer is wrong. dacracot, please, accept Jeni's answer, which is a good one.

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty.  As with any lookup, you need to use current():

/root/bucket[/root/base/tent[@key = current()/tent/@key]/@color = 'blue' or /root/base/tent[@key = current()/tent/@key]/@color = 'red']

Answer (score 0):

JeniT has the appropriate response / code listed here.  You need to create the key before you walk the XML Document, then perform matches against that key.